# Security check in Turin-Caselle or Malpensa airports

Tags: airport-security, turin

Planning a trip to/from Turin airport (TRN) inside Schengen space. A colleague working there advised about occasional usage of body scanners, whilst the airport contact team states these are not deployed on the airport. This is a sort of draw.

Could anyone (with experience departing from Turin airport) comment on the usage of any kind of body scanner machines there?

Alternatively, experience departing from Malpensa (MXP) airport at Milan -also for body scanners- would help as well.

Comment: Why do you need to know this?

Comment: I could be an Italophobe with an expertise on liquid explosives; or I could be a privacy defender; or I could be anything else. Yet, a couple of questions: why would one care about my motivation? And why would they take my word in the first place when they are already suspicious? As with a previous post, years ago, I do not think I need to justify my motivations to avoid that kind of control and thus do not intend to start a debate over these - it is out of the question at hand. PS: security by obscurity possibly does not work that well in real life either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After direct experience, I can confirm that at this point in time and for the Schengen area there are **no** body scanners at all in the Torino airport. Hooray :)

There was just one active track (out of 3/4) with the usual, non-invasive security measures.